# $set and positional operator doesn't work in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have the following document in MongoDb collection called `hosts`

```
{ "_id"   : ObjectId("532aeec040a83df82181ff3c"), 
   "os"   : "WINDOWS", 
   "name" : "Host 1", 
   "bas" : [     
              {   "wwn" : "EE:00:11:FF",  "id" : "1" },   
              {   "wwn" : "AA:00:11:BB",  "id" : "2" } ] 
}
```

Now I want to update `ba` of `id=1` in Host of `name=Host 1` to `{   "wwn" : "AA:BB:CC:DD",  "id" : "11" }`. After the update the result will be

```
{ "_id"   : ObjectId("532aeec040a83df82181ff3c"), 
   "os"   : "WINDOWS", 
   "name" : "Host 1", 
   "bas" : [     
              {   "wwn" : "AA:BB:CC:DD",  "id" : "11" },   
              {   "wwn" : "AA:00:11:BB",  "id" : "2" } ] 
}
```

For this I used the mongo shell command

```
db.hosts.update( { name : "Host 1", "bas.id" : "1" }, 
 { "$set" : { "bas.$" : { wwn : "AA:BB:CC:DD", id : "11"} }} );
```

which **worked great**. Now I wanted to do the same using Java drivers and here is my code

```
BasicDBObject example = new BasicDBObject("name", "Host 1").append("bas\uff0eid", "1");
BasicDBObject newValue = new BasicDBObject("\u0024set",  new BasicDBObject("bas\uff0e\u0024", new BasicDBObject().append("wwn", "AA:BB:CC:DD).append("id","11")) ;
collection.update(example, newValue);
```

In the above code I had to replace `.` with `\uff0` and `$` with `\u0024` to avoid exception being thrown. This update call is **not updating** the collection. When I inspected the `BasicDBObject.toString()` the JSON were same as what I had typed on console. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you should need to write `$` and `.` as Unicode escapes.  I tried running your code with the actual characters in them and it worked fine with the 2.11 Java driver.

But your code has two problems: 1) the full stop `.` is `\u002e`, not `\uff0e`, which is a very different character. 2) the syntax of the last part of the statement is not correct, but that is probably a copying error.

Here's the code that I used, and it worked fine (I only created the objects and didn't actually run it against the database but I don't see why that wouldn't work).

```
    BasicDBObject example = new BasicDBObject("name", "Host 1").append("bas.id", "1");
    BasicDBObject newValue = new BasicDBObject("$set",
                               new BasicDBObject("bas.$",
                                 new BasicDBObject()
                                   .append("wwn", "AA:BB:CC:DD").append("id","11"))) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I am using 2.11.4 and if i use `.`, then I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document field names can't have a . in them. (Bad Key: 'bas.$')`. Thats why I had to switch to unicode.

Comment: You are bang on! the problem was unicode of `.`. Worked great! thank you :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you tell me where the ``IllegalArgumentException`` happened? In which API call exactly?

Comment: it happened when i called `collection.update()`, actually if you check the source code of `DBCollection` class, then `validateKey()` is throwing the exception.

Comment: But it's working for you now? So you are using literal characters for ``$`` and ``.`` in your code and it works?

Comment: I found out.. I was using `2.11.4` where if `$` or `.` used as it is, throws exception. Now I switched to `2.11.0` where without using `unicode` chars things are working fine.. Not sure why they are changing so much in a minor version release

Comment: For the record, I've tried this with the latest version of the Java driver, 2.11.4 and it works without problems. There is no need to escape ``$`` and ``.`` with that driver version (or any other driver version), and there shouldn't be. Something else must have gone wrong when you tried it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/DBCollectionImpl.java#L249

If your value object doesn't have a key starting with $ then it will check the embedded document for illegal characters.  Can you post your original code that had this problem, without the escapes?